# What is this type of SwiftUI appending function pattern called, and how do I make my own?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI Elements and its attributes can be "appended", like so:

```
Text("Hello World")
  .font(.body)
  .frame(maxWidth: 300, alignment: .leading)
  .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 5, trailing: 0))
```

Now I want to create my own, so that instead of writing

```
.background(Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.green))
```

every time I could put that into a function called `coloredDebugBackground()` and then "append" it to every element I want to color, like so

```
Text("Hello World")
  .coloredDebugBackground()
```

I am pretty sure there is some material on this out there, but I don't know what this type/pattern/system is called!

Comment: The word you are looking for is `ViewModifier`.

Comment: @vacawama sweet, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... yes... magic word `ViewModifier`, but actually there is no magic here - all of those your examples are just functions/methods of `View` that generate new view when called. And `ViewModifier` protocol is very useful in case of *heavy* (or active) modifications, but in your simple static modifications case there is a much simpler solution...

Just make direct extension on View and wrap needed calls in one function:

```
extension View {
    func coloredDebugBackground() -> some View {
        self.background(Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.green))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is referred to as Builder pattern. It is described quite well here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/using-the-builder-pattern-in-swift/